# How to make each scene keep its viewport position?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

The viewport camera position is global, so when I'm switching between scenes that have stuff at different locations in the 3D space, I have to continuously move/rotate the viewport so that it looks at something meaningful.

Is there a way for each scene to retain its viewport location/rotation?

[image: screencast showing that camera position stays global between scenes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use local camera in each scene/viewport.
It works reasonably well.

Choose a camera and set it as *Local Camera*.
And then check *Lock Camera to View*

*Set the View panel like in this gif.

Note that I use a different local camera in each scene/viewport.*

[image]

Comment: This works if you keep always viewing through the active camera. It's a good enough workaround, thanks.

Comment: Very smart idea.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 Thanks man. Not mine, but I'll happily take all the credit :).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by giving each scene object its own user. Go to **OBJECT < MAKE SINGLE USER < OBJECT AND DATA**. I'm assuming you want to keep the same material for the objects. This will give each object it's own transformation so that it will not move in other scenes.

Comment: I don't have common objects in the two scenes. I'm talking about the viewport position of the 3D view. I will updated the question with .gif shortly.

Comment: Oh. I don't think you can do that. Sorry.